# Performance implications of calling ToArray inside a LINQ selector

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization, collections

If I have the following statement:

```
whatever.Select(x => collection.ToArray()[index]).ToList();
```

Is LINQ smart enough to perform the `ToArray` cast only once *(I'm not really aware of how this closure is transformed and evaluated)?*

I understand that this code is bad, just interested.

Comment: `ToArray()` is a method call, not a cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it will be performed once for every item in *whatever*.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a peek at the code for [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), especially the [`Select`](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/source/browse/trunk/src/Enumerable.cs#190) method (that ends up calling [`SelectYield`](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/source/browse/trunk/src/Enumerable.cs#214).

The essence of `SelectYield` is a simple for-loop:

```
foreach (var item in source)
    yield return selector(item, i++);
```

Where `selector` is the lambda expression you pass in, in your case `x => collection.ToArray()[index]`. From here it is obvious that the whole lambda expression will be evaluated for every element in `whatever`.

Note that LINQBridge is a stand alone reimplementation of LINQ2Objects and thus not necessarily identical (but to a very large extent at least behaving exactly like LINQ2Objects, including side effects).